# How can I make the article headlines more clean in my homepage?

Tags: website-design, design, homepage

I have a simple webpage where I take notes on various things. I have a few "folders" (topics) and several "files" (articles) under them. My current homepage is like this:

[image]

For example **java** has **class-design** and **collections** and **collectors** and so on. I tried to separate the files with a dot between them but I think it is still needs quite an effort to distinguish single pages.

How can I make it more cleaner so that it is easier on the eyes to realise individual files under a topic?

Comment: The answers are opinion based. There is no right and no wrong answer to this question. Formatting and layout can help as long as you have small number of categories / headlines. If you have more, consider providing search function across all your articles.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a border on each items:

[image: border on each items]

fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nqpyarco/

Comment: More details would be helpful: Is it your personal opinion? Is it result of some user study?

Comment: My personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

### Indenting

[image: Indenting]

### Framing

[image: framing]

### Coloring

[image: coloring]

### Bullets

[image: bullets]

Comment: Tree structure is also helpful

Comment: Am I the only  person who really prefers to frame the titel with the content?